# What kinds of infinite sequences have accumulation points?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convex-analysis

I am actually asking about one particular sequence.

$$ y^k = \frac{x^k - \Pi_{\bar{X}}(x^k)}{\|x^k - \Pi_{\bar{X}}(x^k)\|} $$

Here $x^k$ is a sequence converging to $x^\star$, $x^\star$ is not belonging to open convex set $X$ and $x^k$ is in the exterior of $X$. $\bar{X}$ is the closure of $X$. $\Pi$ means projection. So my question is whether $y^k$ converges or not as $k$ goes to infinity? Or does $y^k$ has accumulation points? The proof in the book (Ruszczynski's 'Nonlinear optimization', theorem 2.15) assumes this accumulation points exist and is a nonzero vector.

Note: this would be trivial considering $x^\star$ in the exterior of $X$. I am actually asking about cases where $x^\star$ is on the boundary of $X$. Any ideas?

Comment: Limited sequences always has convergent subsequence?

Comment: Hi @RafaelHolanda, sorry for confusing description. I add more details about my question. Please see the details. :-)

Answer (score 0):

All right guys, I am a little slow there. First, since the definition of $y^k$ suggests all $\|y^k\| = 1$, thus it's a bounded sequence and must have accumulation points, and it's norm should be 1 so it's nonzero vector. Problem solved.

However, when $x^\star$ is in the exterior of $X$, this limit should be the vector pointing from $\Pi_{\bar{X}}(x^\star)$ to $x^\star$. Then what about the case when $x^\star$ is on the boundary? What will the limit be? That could be another question.